# PHP foreach loop inserts the last element twice

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

I am trying to insert values to a database with a foreach loop.
 It all works fine but the last element of the array gets inserted twice.

I understand that a reference of a `$photo` and the last array element remain even after the foreach loop.
 I am trying to destroy it by using `unset($photo)` but that does not seem to work, I still get double insert inside my database of the last element.

Can someone explain this to me?

```
// value of $photos

 <?php 
     $stmt = $conn->prepare(
        "SELECT p.*, pt.propertyType
        FROM tbl_property p
        JOIN tbl_propertyType pt USING (PropertyType_Id)
        ORDER BY Price;"
    ); 
    $stmt->execute();
    ?>

 <form id = "prop-form" action="../scripts/photo-property.php" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select name="property">
        <?php while($row = $stmt->fetch()){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['Property_Id'];?>"><?php echo $row['propertyType'] . ', ' . 'Price: ' . $row['Price'] . ', ' . $row['BuildingNameStreetNo'] 
            . ', ' . $row['Street'] . ', ' . $row['Town'] . ', ' . $row['Condition'] 
            . ', ' . $row['RoomNo'] . ' Rooms'; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>

<?php $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_Photo");
            $sql->execute();
            while($row = $sql->fetch()){
                echo '<img class="propimg" src=../photos/'. $row['Photo'] . '><br/>'; 
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="photos[]" value="'. $row['Photo_Id'] . '">';
            }
        ?>
</form>

------------- 
// DIFFERENT FILE

// assign the array values from the form
        $photos = $_POST['photos'];


        // for each photo, bind the param and execute the query
        $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_propertyphoto (Property_Id, Photo_Id) VALUES (:prop, :photo)");
        foreach($photos as $photo) {

            $sql->bindParam(':prop', $_POST['property']);
            $sql->bindValue(':photo', $photo);
            $sql->execute();

        }
         unset($photo);
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Is it full code fragment?

Comment: yes, Alex. It is the full code.

Comment: Are you sure that the issue is stemming from the php side? What does the post request contain? What's the value of ` $_POST['photos']`?

Comment: could you please remove `try...catch` and extract `$sql = $conn->prepare(` to put it before the loop starts.

Comment: removed try catch and added code on what is the $photos value

Comment: "and added code on what is the $photos value" - no you did not

Comment: sorry, made it clearer now.

Comment: post the output if you do `print_r($photos);` right after `$photos = $_POST['photos'];`

Comment: What is written in your code is one thing, what it outputs is another and what is sent from the client is the third. Franky, your output code helps nothing. It's the input data that contains an extra row

Comment: I selected 4 photos.
thats the output: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 [3] => 5 )

Comment: Where is input id 'property' in your form?

Comment: delboy1978uk  addede it now

Comment: Fragment is still not complete one. `while($row = $stmt->fetch()){ ?>` variable `$stmt` is not defined anywhere

Comment: defined it now, Alex

Answer (score 0):

Check if your `tbl_Photo` table hasn't multiple of the same rows.

Try to make the columns `Property_Id` and `Photo_Id` UNIQUE together.
In that way you cannot have the same combination twice.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_propertyphoto ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Property_Photo UNIQUE(Property_Id, Photo_Id)
```

Comment: however that way i get a fatal error due to duplicate entry

Comment: You only get the fatal error for the last row, if you are running in live environment you should turn off errors so the page will work and insert your rows, but the last row will get an error hidden in background and will not be inserted while the others rows will be inserted